# File manipulation on a genome file

Tags: python, awk

I have a genome file (size: ~840 MB and 13801301 lines) of the following format ('genome.txt')

```
>SL3.0ch00
AATAATAATAATAATAATAATAATAAATAAATAAATAAATAATAATAATAATAATAATAA
TAAATAAATAAATAAATAAATAAATAAATAAATAATAATAATAATAATAATAATAATAAT
AATAATAATAATAATAATAATAATAATAATAATAATAATAATAATAATAATAATAATAAT
AATAATAATAATAATAATAATAATAATAAAAATAATAATAATAATAATAATAATAATAAT
>SL3.0ch01
TAGAGGATCTTGGAGGAGGTTCATTGCTGCAGATATTCCATTCATCCGATTTCCTCCAAG
ATGTACCGCGATTTGAGAGAGGTATATTGGTGGGAAGGCAAAGAGAGAGATATTGTTGCC
AAGTACCTGAGTTGCCAACAAGTGAAAGTAGAGCACCAAAGTCCTGGAGGTTTGGCTCAA
ACTTTAGAACTTCTTGAATGGAAGTGGAGATAAATAACATGGACTTTATCACAGGTTTGC
>SL3.0ch02
ATGTACCGCGATTTGAGAGAGGTATATTGGTGGGAAGGCAAAGAGAGAGATATTGTTGCC
AAGTACCTGAGTTGCCAACAAGTGAAAGTAGAGCACCAAAGTCCTGGAGGTTTGGCTCAA
ACTTTAGAACTTCTTGAATGGAAGTGGAGATAAATAACATGGACTTTATCACAGGTTTGC
AAAGATCTCGAAGGCAACATGACTCTAGGTGATTTTCGATAGAATGACAAAGTCATCCCT
```

I want to remove the new line characters and all the tags '>SL3.0ch00' so that I have a uniform string of letters (without any space/newline/tags) in a file. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Open the file in notepad and remove them by hand.

Comment: @LeDYoM edit 13801301 lines _by hand_?

Comment: The result will not be a POSIX text file since it won't end in a newline and so YMMV with running any subsequent tools on it (e.g. `wc -l` will tell you there are no lines in the file). Are you sure that's what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grep` and `tr`:

```
grep -v '>' file | tr -d '\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS=""}; !/>/{print}' test.txt
```

ORS is the Output Record Separator Variable. Set to "", it removes \n

!/>/ selects lines that do not contain >

Comment: in a shorter form:  `awk '!/>/' ORS="" text.txt`